# is it possible to use my pc's current ip-address for foreign deployed puppeteer browser as if it was a valid proxy but without any proxy or vpn

Tags: deployment, proxy, puppeteer, ip-address, vpn

Because there is no proxy or vpn support in my country, i am severely trying to figure out how this can be done: I am trying to automate a website's task using puppeteer and i wanted the puppeteer's browser instance to interact with the website only using my country's ip-address and simulating it is from here not from the place where i have deployed. i have no problem with the specification of the ip address or anything the only thing i want is i want puppeteer do its task as if it was from here in my country not from the deployed place which is in `Europe`. for further information the platform is `render.com`.

I have tried using my laptop as a personal server because this is the only source of my country's ip address but this is not effective way of doing it.

Comment: Probably not with render.com but if you ran it on a vps you could reverse ssh tunnel to it